# boolForKey unrecognized selector error iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, boolean

I am reading from a plist file into an array. When I iterate through the array I save each string it to its respective part of the data structure. When I get to the BOOL variable and try boolForKey to extract it from the array I get an unrecoginized selector error.

Here is some code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<myArray.count;i++){

[myDataStructure setName:[[myArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:NAMEVAR_KEY]];
//works fine
....
[myDataStructure setABoolVar:[[myArray objectAtIndex:i] boolForKey:BOOLVAR_KEY]];
//crash
.... 
}
```

The properties in the data structure are like this:
    @property(nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;
    @property(nonatomic) BOOL aBoolVar;

```
//synthesized etc....
```

In the plist, the property is listed as a Boolen, if I use objectForKey I get a warning but it doesn't crash.

Any ideas?

This is the XML

```
<dict>
<key>Root</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Bobby</string>
        <key>aBoolValue</key>
        <true/>

    </dict>
....
    </array>
</dict>
```

....

From the console

```
2012-02-16 23:45:21.866 CSOTest4[1452:f803] -[__NSCFDictionary boolForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d296a0
2012-02-16 23:45:21.867 CSOTest4[1452:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary boolForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d296a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13c2052 0x1553d0a 0x13c3ced 0x1328f00 0x1328ce2 0x3980 0xdf64e 0xdec1c 0x10556d 0xefd47 0x106441 0x10645d 0x10645d 0x1064f9 0x46d65 0x46dac 0x17be6 0x188a6 0x27743 0x281f8 0x1baa9 0x12acfa9 0x13961c5 0x12fb022 0x12f990a 0x12f8db4 0x12f8ccb 0x182a7 0x19a9b 0x2618 0x2575 0x1)
```

Comment: Please post the exact text of the error you are getting

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NSDictionary does not have a method called `boolForKey`. You have to use `objectForKey` first, which will give you an NSNumber, and then call `boolValue` on the NSNumber.

```
BOOL myBool = [[[myArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:BOOLVAR_KEY] boolValue];
```

or to break it down into pieces:

```
NSDictionary myDictionary = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
NSNumber myNumber = [myDictionary objectForKey:BOOLVAR_KEY];
BOOL myBool = [myNumber boolValue];
```

Comment: Both solutions worked, I wish I could split the credit. Now it makes sense why I was getting a selector error, it compiled OK without warnings though. Thats the part that thew me off. Sometimes it seems that if code compiles without warnings it will work. Thats not always the case.

Comment: @j_mcnally you should probably try to edit your answer so that it contains the solution that you reached in the comments. Otherwise it looks like the solution was just to use YES instead of true.

Comment: I was stumped why I couldn't get a useful value out of a boolean plist field using objectForkey: alone. After reading this answer, I still don't understand why it doesn't just work, but at least my code works now.

Answer (score 0):

Should your boolean in your PLIST be  YES  rather than True?

This works

```
[myDataStructure setABoolVar:([(NSDictionary*) 
        [myArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:BOOLVAR_KEY]== 
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]?YES:NO)];
```

Comment: Right now it is set to YES, let me try TRUE.

Comment: Didnt do anything, when you type TRUE into the plist on xcode it automatically makes it YES. But I thought it was clever to try anyway

Comment: Try Casting you array result as an NSDictionary
[myDataStructure setABoolVar:[(NSDictionary *)[myArray objectAtIndex:i] boolForKey:BOOLVAR_KEY]];

Comment: build failure;  Receiver type NSDictionary for instance message foes not declare a method with selector boolForKey

Comment: use valueForKey instead of boolForKey, from what i can ascertain, you can only store objects in NSDictionary so booleans are converted to NSNumbers. So you may get a NSNumber back with a 1 or 0, but thats better than nothing.

Comment: My NSLog generates an output of 21335912

Comment: oh wait, I changed %d to %@ since NSNumber is an object.... now I get back appropriate 1 and 0 values

Comment: Should I change my data structure implementation, from BOOL to NSNumber maybe? To avoid the warnings

Comment: You can or you could use a ternary to convert back to Boolean. // BOOL something = (number == 1) ? YES : NO;

Comment: I can successfully NSLog the value before I write to the data structure, however, reading %d from the data structure returns unexpected values.

Comment: Because NSLog(%d) expects a decimal, NSNumber is a pointer so you must use %@

Comment: Actually NSNumber has a boolVal so you can do [number boolValue]

Comment: Ok got it to work, here is my fraken-code... lol... [myDataStructure setABoolVar:([(NSDictionary*)[myArray  objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:BOOLVAR_KEY]==[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]?YES:NO)];   This seemed to do the trick, thank you. And no warnings too :)

Comment: Sorry, if i had more time id help you clean it up, did you try [NSNumber boolValue] instead of the ternary?

Comment: No worries, screw it, as long as it works for now. Ill work on it more later. Thanks again